# get Result of method inside viewModelScope

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to mvvm. So I want to ask how to retrieve the result of the method executed in viewModelScope.
In my example I want to save a book in database and retrieve the saved book. Is there a better way to do it?

```
fun addBook (book:Book): BookEntity {
    var bookEntity = BookEntity()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        bookEntity = repository.addBook(book)
    }
    return bookEntity
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coroutine, launched in `addBook` method using `launch` builder, will be executed after the function returns, so `bookEntity` will no be reassigned  with a new value from DB. You should think about how you want to use the data. If you want it to be used just as an input data for some another calculations then it make sense to make the `addBook()` function `suspend`:

```
suspend fun addBook(): BookEntity {
    val bookEntity = repository.addBook(book) // I assume function repository.addBook(book) is suspend
    return bookEntity
}
```

If you want it to be displayed in UI you can make it `suspend` like above and call it in a coroutine using [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope):

in `Activity`/`Fragment`

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val book = viewModel.addBook()
    // update UI
}
```

Another alternative is to apply reactive approach using [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) or Kotlin [`Flow`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow)